# python requests: can I use s.mount() consecutively?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a piece of code that does a lot of requests to a website, therefore I have implemented some kind of retry logic in case of some intermittent failure. I also need to use a different IP, so I have this piece of code:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters.source import SourceAddressAdapter

new_source = SourceAddressAdapter(ip)
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries = 20)

sess = requests.Session()
sess.mount('http://', adapter)
sess.mount('https://', adapter)
sess.mount('http://', new_source)
sess.mount('https://', new_source)
```

I was wondering whether it is okay or not to use sess.mount() two times or if using it the second time will "overwrite" my first parameter (adapter). I need both to use the IP and the retry adapter during my session.

How can I do that if sess.mount() doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

`SourceAddressAdapter` inherited from `HTTPAdapter` and it also proxies kwargs to `HTTPAdapter.__init__()`:

```
class SourceAddressAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, source_address, **kwargs):
        ### Some code ###
        super(SourceAddressAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/blob/master/requests_toolbelt/adapters/source.py

So you just can use it with `max_retries` kwarg:

```
adapter = SourceAddressAdapter(ip, max_retries=20)
```

P.S. Yep, I'm late, however someone may google this question just like me.

Comment: This is the right answer for this specific question. Only one adapter may be used per prefix because the adapters are kept in a dictionary internally keyed by the prefix. https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/_modules/requests/sessions/#Session.mount