# How may I combine multiple adapters in Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to make multiple calls to a web endpoint that is somewhat unreliable, so I have put together a timeout/retry strategy that I issue to a `requests.Session()` object as an adapter.

However, I *also* need to mount this same endpoint using a client PKCS12 certificate and a public certificate authority (verify), which I can easily perform with the `requests_pkcs12` package - this also creates an adapter.

So, adapter 1 looks like this, (pieced together with things I found across the internet):

```
# timeout.py

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30

class TimeoutAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
        if "timeout" in kwargs:
            self.timeout = kwargs["timeout"]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        timeout = kwargs.get("timeout")
        if timeout is None:
            kwargs["timeout"] = self.timeout
        return super().send(request, **kwargs)

## set up adapter
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
    
    u = 'https://some-webservice.com'
    s = requests.Session()
    retry_strategy = Retry(
        total=10,
        status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
        backoff_factor=1)
    s.mount(u, adapter=TimeoutAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
```

Then, the second adapter looks like this:

```
from requests import Session
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter

pki_adapter = Pkcs12Adapter(
    pkcs12_filename='path/to/cert.p12',
    pkcs12_password='cert-password')

u = 'https://some-webservice.com'
s = requests.Session()
s.mount(u, adapter=pki_adapter)
```

Both work lovely by themselves, but how would I go about merging them into a single adapter so that the session uses the PKI to authenticate, but also honors the timeout/retry strategy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python requests: can I use s.mount() consecutively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370124/python-requests-can-i-use-s-mount-consecutively)

Comment: I can't test it this second but since `requests_pkcs12.Pkcs12Adapter` inherits from `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter`, I should be able to simply set up the `retry_strategy` as normal, and do: `s.mount(u, adapter=Pkcs12Adapter(cert, pw, verify, max_retries=retry_strategy)`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the default timeout behavior from `TimeoutAdapter`, then since `TimeoutAdapter` and `Pkcs12Adapter` both inherit from `HTTPAdapter`, you can have the former inherit from the latter (single inheritance). For example:

```py
# timeout.py

from requests import Session
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30

class TimeoutAdapter(Pkcs12Adapter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
        if "timeout" in kwargs:
            self.timeout = kwargs["timeout"]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        timeout = kwargs.get("timeout")
        if timeout is None:
            kwargs["timeout"] = self.timeout
        return super().send(request, **kwargs)

## set up adapter
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
    
    retry_strategy = Retry(
        total=10,
        status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
        backoff_factor=1)

    timeout_adapter = TimeoutAdapter(
        max_retries=retry_strategy,
        pkcs12_filename='path/to/cert.p12',
        pkcs12_password='cert-password'
    )

    u = 'https://some-webservice.com'
    s = requests.Session()
    s.mount(u, adapter=timeout_adapter)
```

Comment: Precisely what I'm looking for.  Gives the ability to offer it as an optional connection class if not needed in certain cases.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered to do something like this?

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import requests
import logging

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30

class TimeoutPkcs12Adapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, pkcs12_filename, pkcs12_password, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, **kwargs):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.pkcs12_adapter = Pkcs12Adapter(pkcs12_filename=pkcs12_filename, pkcs12_password=pkcs12_password)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False, **pool_kwargs):
        # Load certificate details into pool manager
        pool_kwargs['cert_file'] = self.pkcs12_adapter.cert_file
        pool_kwargs['key_file'] = self.pkcs12_adapter.key_file
        super().init_poolmanager(connections, maxsize, block, **pool_kwargs)

    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('timeout', self.timeout)
        try:
            return super().send(request, **kwargs)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            logging.error(f"Request failed: {e}")
            raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://some-webservice.com'
    session = requests.Session()
    retry_strategy = Retry(total=10, status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504], backoff_factor=1)
    adapter = TimeoutPkcs12Adapter(
        pkcs12_filename='path/to/cert.p12',
        pkcs12_password='cert-password',
        max_retries=retry_strategy
    )
    session.mount(url, adapter)
```

it will help you combine to adapters by inheritance.

Update: previous code had Diamond issue.

Comment: Thanks!  But did you mean `class TimeoutPkcs12Adapter(HTTPAdapter, Pkcs12Adapter):`?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for my mistake, it should inherit from HTTPAdapter

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me a `Cannot create consistent method ordering` in the class.  inheritance is tricky

Comment: tried it locally and it worked, the previous answer had diamond issue.

Comment: Thanks again - in this case, what does the key file represent?  PKCS12 bundles are decrypted in memory and do not have key files, so I guess I could just leave it out?  I do have a CA (.crt) file that `Session().verify` will point to, but for clients, everything is in one .p12 file.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it properly without key_file, but please try and let me know, I may learn something from it as well, thanks <3

Comment: I ended up marking @booboo's answer, though it was very close to yours, the order may be helpful to you too.  I do thank you for your time and responses though, they were still helpful!